# Java synthetic method and bridge method confusion

Tags: java, reflection, java-synthetic-methods

As stated in [Effects of Type Erasure and Bridge Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html#bridgeMethods) a bridge method implies that it is also a synthetic method. The question is, is it possible that invocation of `isSynthetic` method returns true but `isBridge` method returns false for a `Method` object, i.e., if a method is synthetic does it imply that it is also a bridge method?

**It's not exactly the same but the source code for `isSynthetic` and `isBridge` methods looks like below:**

```
static final int SYNTHETIC = 0x00001000;
public boolean isSynthetic() {
    return (getModifiers() & SYNTHETIC) != 0;
}

static final int BRIDGE = 0x00000040;
public boolean isBridge() {
    return (getModifiers() & BRIDGE) != 0;
}
```

Why `isBridge` method body is not like `return isSynthetic();`?

Comment: These methods are just returning the value of the corresponding modifier; the class is probably just a data holder. Crucial is the logic of how the modifiers are set.

Comment: I was thinking the same. The modifiers are set through constructor. But I can not find a usage for it.

Comment: Related question for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557586/java-generics-bridge-method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are simply looking for an example of such:

```
Function<String, Integer> func = s -> s.length();

Arrays.stream(DeleteMe.class.getDeclaredMethods())
     .peek(m -> System.out.println(m.getName() + " isSynth : " + m.isSynthetic() + " isBridge : " + m.isBridge()))
     .forEach(System.out::println);
```

There will be entries like:

```
lambda$0 isSynth : true isBridge : false
lambda$1 isSynth : true isBridge : false
```

Comment: Another example would be the `access$n` methods generated when an inner class accesses `private` members of the outer class and vice versa.

Comment: @Holger didnt think of these :)

Answer (score 1):

Bridge is synthetic but synthetic is not necessarily bridge. Example:

```
public class Test {

    public Test clone() {
        return null;
    }
```

bytecode outline:

```
  // access flags 0x1041
  public synthetic bridge clone()Ljava/lang/Object; throws java/lang/CloneNotSupportedException 
   L0
...
```

Comment: I get two clone methods by invoking getDeclaredMethods() on your Test class. One of them is both synthetic and bridge.

Comment: clone() with Object return type is bridge method created by compiler to override Object.clone(). All implicit methods created by compiler are synthetic, but they are created for different purposes.

Comment: I know what is synthetic, I just wanted to point out that your answer need a clarification. The one you gave is not enough to clarify your conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible that invocation of `isSynthetic` method returns true but `isBridge` method returns false for a Method object

Yes, it is possible.

For example, the method [AbstractPipeline](https://openjdk.binarydoc.org/net.java/openjdk/13.0/classfile?classfilelocation=java.util.stream.abstractpipeline).[lambda$spliterator$0()](https://openjdk.binarydoc.org/net.java/openjdk/13.0/method?classfilelocation=java.util.stream.abstractpipeline&seq=37&methodname=lambda%24spliterator%240) is `synthetic` but is it **NOT** `bridge`.

According to the [JVM Spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se13/html/jvms-4.html):

- The `ACC_SYNTHETIC` flag indicates that this method was generated by a compiler and does not appear in source code
- The `ACC_BRIDGE` flag is used to indicate a bridge method generated by a compiler for the Java programming language.

So,

- A `bridge` method is 100% sure it is `synthetic`
- A `synthetic` method is not necessary `bridge`

### More on `bridge` method

Based on [What is Java Bridge Method (ACC_BRIDGE)](https://binarydoc.blogspot.com/2019/10/what-is-java-bridge-method-accbridge.html) the `bridge` method is generated by Java Compiler for [type erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure) purpose of Java Generics.